# Vladimir Voevodskys 2002 ICM Lecture.

Tags: soft-question, reference-request

Is Vladimir Voevodskys ICM lecture available in videotaped format somewhere?
Strangely it is not at the IMU homepage (but Lafforgues is) http://www.mathunion.org/Videos/ICM2002/

Was it not taped (Why not?)?
If not is at least a transcript available somewhere?
Is there a least video of the opening ceremony, and the Laudatio(s)?

Are there any taped lectures of Voevodsky lecturing on Motivic Cohomology?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some of Voevodsky videos are here:

http://video.ias.edu/taxonomy/term/42

http://www.mathnet.ru/PresentFiles/425/425.flv

http://www.mathunion.org/Videos/ICM98/ICMs/vladimir_voevodsky.html

http://claymath.msri.org/voevodsky2002.mov

The last two talks, *Algebraic Cycles and Motives* and *An Intuitive Introduction to Motivic Homotopy Theory*, are perhaps the closest to what you look for. As for the last talk, the notes from it are available here:

http://www.cwru.edu/artsci/phil/Voevodsky.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had found the first two earlier, but the last two are indeed exactly what I was looking for. Thanks